# call variables inside object scope

Tags: javascript

I have a JS file with this object setup amount other objects.

```
     if (!me) var me = {};

        me.page = {


            initialize:function( options ) {
                var settings = $.extend({
                    error_module: $('#error-module'),
                    mainForm: $('form')
                }, options);

            },
            pagemaker:function(){
               var temp = settings.error_module
            }
        }

        me.bla = {
          // the scope of bla
        }
```

if I call me.page.pagemaker() it can't find the settings variable. I don't want to make settings global I want it to be in scope with the object page. 
How can I make this work so var temp = settings.error_module is not undefined.

Comment: FYI `var me = me || {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a property of `me`:

```
initialize:function( options ) {
    me.settings = ...;

}
```

And later:

```
pagemaker:function(){
   var temp = me.settings.error_module
}
```

You also have a scope problem here:

```
if (!me) var me = {};
```

You could use this instead:

```
var me = me || {};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). See if this helps. I slightly modified your code to what I would consider best practice:

```
var me = me || (function(){
  var settings = {
    errorModule: '#error-module',
    mainForm: 'form'
  };
  return {
    page: {
      init: function(options) {
        $.extend(settings, options);
      },
      pageMaker: function() {
        var temp = $(settings.errorModule);
      }
    },
    bla: function() {

    }
  };
}());
```

**Edit:** Missed the outer object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it within the scope of the object page, you can define another attribute called `settings` in your `page` object since it's just represented by keys and values, like so:

```
me.page = {

  // Initial/default values
  settings: {
    error_module: null,
    mainForm: null,
  },

  initialize: function(options) {
    this.settings = $.extend({...}, options);
  },

  pagemaker: function() {
    var temp = this.settings.error_module;
  }
}
```

Comment: This.settings is showing as undefined. The only way I can get to it from another method inside me.page is by using. me.page.settings